# Add IPv6 To Google Cloud SQL Whitelist / Authorization

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

How do I add a IPv6 to my authorized/whitelisted networks for Google Cloud SQL?

[Click to see Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soi4o.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the *Cloud SQL* instance you're using 1st or 2nd generation?

2nd generation *Cloud SQL* instances do not support `IPv6`, as per stated in the official documentation that you can check [**here**](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#appaccessIP).

---

**EDIT:**

There is an existing feature request on the *Google Issue Tracker* to add `CloudSQL v2` instances support for whitelisting `IPv6`. You can check the status of the request [**by following this link**](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#appaccessIP). You can use the “star” on the top left corner to get updates on the state of the request.

> As a workaround, what you can do is to configure authentication based
>   on a client certificate and connect using `IPv4`. You can use a web
>   service like [**config.me**](http://config.me) to get your `IPv4` address by running
>   this command: `$ curl --ipv4 ifconfig.me`

Comment: Got it. Can you suggest an alternative option? My home network has a IPv6 and I need to access the SQL DB from my home.

Comment: There is an existing feature request on the Google Issue Tracker to add CloudSQL v2 instances support for whitelisting IPv6.
We can’t provide regular updates on feature requests, as resolution can take days or weeks. 
You can check the status of the request by following this link [1].
You can use the “star” on the top left corner to get updates on the state of the request.

[1] https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72219717

Comment: Hello Will, what you can do is to configure authentication based on a client certificate and connect using IPv4.

Comment: You can use a web service like config.me to get your IPv4 address by running this command: curl --ipv4 ifconfig.me